# yumdownloader not installed the latest rpm version

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, repository

we installed the epel repo , in order to download some rpm for docker on rhel 7.x

reference - https://www.centlinux.com/2019/02/install-docker-ce-on-offline-centos-7-machine.html

```
 yum repolist | grep epel
epel/x86_64               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  13,257
```

now we want to download some required rpm as

```
yumdownloader --resolve libseccomp
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libseccomp.i686 0:2.2.1-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.2.1-1.el7 will be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

ls -ltr | grep libseccomp


ls -ltr | grep libseccomp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    50612 Nov 10  2016 libseccomp-2.2.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    48972 Nov 10  2016 libseccomp-2.2.1-1.el7.i686.rpm
```

but we are very surprised that `yumdownload` not download the latest version

- ( http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libseccomp.html )

why yumdownloader - , not download the latest rpm version ?

Note - the reasons that we want the latest version because :

```
 rpm -ivh --replacefiles --replacepkgs *.rpm
warning: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 621e9f35: NOKEY
warning: container-selinux-2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
warning: package docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch was already added, replacing with docker-ce-3:19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
warning: libseccomp-2.2.1-1.el7.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        policycoreutils >= 2.5-11 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch
        selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-216.el7 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch
        selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-216.el7 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch
        selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-216.el7 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libseccomp` package is part of RHEL and not EPEL so you will be downloading it from the RHEL repos once you have registered with subscription-manager. The version in RHEL 7 is 
libseccomp-2.3.1-4.el7.

Comment: so do you suggest to download all rpm's from redhat repo , by subscriber manager ?

Comment: btw - also selinux-policy  , selinux-policy-base , selinux-policy-targeted

Comment: Yes, that is how RHEL works.

Comment: And just to be sure, you still use yumdownloader. It’s just you need to register first to get access to the yum repositories.

Comment: ok I will do that and I will update , since we have dependencies problem I will not close this post for now until understanding all issues , hope its ok from your point?

Comment: I suggest using “yum install /path/to/packages.rpm” instead of the rpm command. It’ll do a better job of pulling in dependencies.

Comment: from my experience , rpm -ivh --replacefiles  do the right Job

Comment: please take a look on https://www.centlinux.com/2019/02/install-docker-ce-on-offline-centos-7-machine.html , they are using it

Comment: Are those instructions why you are using an out of date version of RHEL instead of 7.8?  It is still better to use `yum`.